# Angularjs not trusting HTML in custom directive despite $sce.trustAsHtml()

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS.  I am trying to create a custom directive that implements a tabbed notebook, with pages.  Here it is on JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/kdtop/rxuchg1t/

On tab 2, notice that one can see: "Content [B]for[/B] tab 2".  I.e. the [B] [/B] tags are not rendered.

Here is the definition of the directive where I try to use $sce.trustAsHtml():

```
MyApp.directive('tmgTabsCtrl', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?tabControl',
    scope: {
        tabControl: '=',
    },
    template: '                                                                    \
    <BR>                                                                           \
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">                                                      \
      <li ng-repeat="i in range(0, tabControl.Tabs.Count()-1)"                     \
        ng-class="{active: tabControl.IsSelected(i)}"                              \
        ng-click="alert(\'test\')" >                                               \
        <a href="#{{i}}"  ng-click="ToggleActive(i)">{{tabControl.TabName(i)}}</a> \
      </li>                                                                        \
    </ul>                                                                          \
    <div class="tab-content">                                                      \
      {{trustAsHtml(tabControl.TabContent()) }}                                    \
    </div>  ',

    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.range = RangeFn;
        scope.ToggleActive = function (Index) {
            scope.tabControl.Select(Index);
        };
        scope.trustAsHtml = function (Html) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(Html);
        };
    }
};
}]);
```

My ultimate goal is to allow the tabControl.Content() function to return text with HTML will all sorts of HTML, including other custom directives as a form of web components.

Do I need to $compile() the text somehow?  What am I doing wrong??

I have tried reviewing the other questions that StackOverflow links as similar, but I can't find an answer to my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I don't know why my first approach didn't work, but below is an approach that does work.

The general idea is the Html in the templateURL creates a DOM element that will hold tab content.  When the user clicks a different tab, then that element is retrieved and then altered using jquery's functionality, e.g. element.html() function.  Then Angular is asked to scan the html and make it interactive via $compile(element)(scope).

Hope this helps someone.  I still wish someone would explain why using .trustAsHtml() method didn't work.....

```
MyApp.directive('tmgTabs', ['$sce', '$compile', '$timeout', function ($sce, $compile, $timeout) {
  var DirectiveObj = {
    restrict: 'E',                                                   
    require: '?tabControl',
    scope: {
      tabControl: '=',
    },                                   
    templateUrl: 'part/tab_part.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.range = RangeFn;
      scope.CompileContent = function(HtmlStr) {
        var el = $("#TMG-TAB-"+scope.tabControl.InstanceID+"-CONTENT"); //jquery object  
        el.html(HtmlStr);
        $compile(el)(scope);          
      };
      scope.DisplayContent = function() {
        scope.CompileContent(scope.tabControl.TabContent());
      };    
      scope.ToggleActive = function(Index){
        scope.tabControl.Select(Index);
        scope.DisplayContent();
      };
      $timeout(function() {              
        scope.ToggleActive(0); //needs to be done after link() finishes.
      });  
    }
  };               
  return DirectiveObj;    
}]);
```

And here is tab_part.html

```
<BR>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li ng-repeat="i in range(0, tabControl.Tabs.Count()-1)"
    ng-class="{active: tabControl.IsSelected(i)}" > 
    <a ng-click="ToggleActive(i)">{{tabControl.TabName(i)}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<span id={{"TMG-TAB-"+tabControl.InstanceID+"-CONTENT"}}>
 <!-- User content will be inserted here-->
</span>
```

And here is an example of use.

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyAppController">  
  <tmg-tabs tab-control="DemoTabs"></tmg-tabs>
</div>
```